# How to add a class to a `li` in an Orchard Content List?

Tags: themes, orchardcms

I am using Orchard 1.8, have created a new theme, and am trying to implement the Blog Post List as a [Bootstrap List Group](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#list-group). Here is the markup that the Bootstrap List Group requires. We need to add a class to both the `ul` and to each `li`.

```
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
</ul>
```

I am stuck on step three of my implementation.

1. Add Bootstrap to the Layout. Done.
2. Add a `list-group` class to the `ul` of the Parts_Blogs_BlogPost_List shape. Done.
3. Add a `list-group-item` class to each `li`. Not Done.

**How do I add a `list-group-item` class to each `li`?**

Add Bootstrap to the Layout. Done.

[image: Add Bootstrap in Layout]

Add a `list-group` class to the `ul` of the Parts_Blogs_BlogPost_List shape. Done.

[image: Add a <code>list-group</code> class to the <code>ul</code> of the BlogPostList shape]

When doing my implementation, I used Shape Tracing to determine that I needed to modify the Parts_Blogs_BlogPost_List shape and its Parts.Blogs.BlogPost.List.cshtml template to add the `list-group` class to the `ul` element. How, though, do we add a `list-group-item` to each `li` element?

Answer (score 1):

In the Parts.Blogs.BlogPost.List.cshtml template, add the following line of code:

```
Model.ContentItems.ItemClasses.Add("list-group-item");
```

Your finished Bootstrap List Group template will look like this:

```
@{
    IEnumerable<object> blogPosts = Model.ContentItems;
    Model.ContentItems.Classes.Add("content-items");
    Model.ContentItems.Classes.Add("blog-posts");
    Model.ContentItems.Classes.Add("list-group");
    Model.ContentItems.ItemClasses.Add("list-group-item");
}

@Display(Model.ContentItems)

@if (blogPosts == null || blogPosts.Count() < 1) {
    <p>@T("There are no posts for this blog.")</p>
}
```

You can research this yourself via Shape Tracing > Model:

[image]